# Connect-AzAccount InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, devops, azure-powershell, ubuntu-20.04

Due to some reasons, I've to reset my OS and now I've to setup everything in my OS. I'm using ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS. After installing the powershell module (pwsh), I'm trying to connect the Azure portal using this command:

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

But cannot able to login into my azure portal account.

And it shows me this error:

**Connect-AzAccount: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)**

Also, I've tried to Connect using my username and password and used this script:

```
$User = "xxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<Password>" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "<tenant id>"
$subscription = "<subscription id>"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $User,$PWord
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -Subscription $subscription
```

But Cannot able to login and it showing me the error:

**Connect-AzAccount: UsernamePasswordCredential authentication failed: Retry failed after 4 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/usernamepasswordcredential/troubleshoot**

Require expert help here.

Comment: Are proxy being used behind the scenes? which version of powershell is being used?

Comment: Nope, no proxy is using behind and the powershell version is: PowerShell 7.2.7

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

I have created Virtual machine With image of Linux ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS as the ***linux image does not come with pre-built UI***, I have installed **`xrdp`** to enable desktop **`GUI`** .

Here, are the commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install xfce4
sudo apt install xfce4-session
sudo apt-get -y install xrdp
sudo systemctl enable xrdp
sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
```

After I installed module of **`Powershell`** with using [*MS-Docs*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-ubuntu?view=powershell-7.2#installation-via-package-repository)
Here are the commands:

```
# Update the list of packages
sudo apt-get update
# Install pre-requisite packages.
sudo apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https software-properties-common
# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
wget -q "https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb"
# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
# Update the list of packages after we added packages.microsoft.com
sudo apt-get update
# Install PowerShell
sudo apt-get install -y powershell
# Start PowerShell
pwsh
```

Once the PS module was installed, install the azure module:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

I tried connecting to Azure portal using below command , I got an same error:

```sql
Connect-AzAccount
```

[image]

After that I tried with commands with **`Device-login`**

```
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
```

[image]

You need click or copy the link and paste it in browser of same Ubuntu machine. if you don't have any browser in you machine try to use below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

**Enter your code:**

[image]

Sign in with your account and click **`continue.`**

[image]

You will notify by you have signed in browser.

[image]

**Console:**
After it is notified in browser, Here in console it is signed **`successfully`** with my Azure Account.

[image]

**Reference:**
[Use xrdp with Linux - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop?tabs=azure-cli)